# pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound: The resource could not be found

Tags: python, exception, pyramid

I am working off of Safari's Pyramid tutorial

> WEB APPLICATIONS WITH PYTHON AND THE PYRAMID FRAMEWORK

Inside of my `views.py` file I having a problem with the following code:

```
@property
def current(self):
    todo_id = self.request.matchdict.get('id')
    todo = sample_todos.get(todo_id)
    if not todo:
        raise HTTPNotFound()
    return todo
```

particularly when the following view function calls this property

```
@view_config(route_name='view', renderer='templates/view.jinja2')
def view(self):
    return dict(todo=self.current)
```

when I am running the application `http://0.0.0.0:6543/5` will not trigger the anticipated `HTTPNotFound()`, see route below.

```
config.add_route('view', '/{id}')
```

the error logs return:

```
  File "/Users/alex/zdev/t-oreilly/mysite/views.py", line 50, in view
    return dict(todo=self.current)
  File "/Users/alex/zdev/t-oreilly/mysite/views.py", line 25, in current
    raise HTTPNotFound()
pyramid.httpexceptions.HTTPNotFound: The resource could not be found.
```

On the browser waitress returns a default server error.

**What is the proper way to remove this error?**

---

I have uploaded this work to [github](https://github.com/AlexanderMcNulty/oreilly-pyramid-tutorial), commit **aaf562e**

the tutorial link is [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/web-applications-with/9781771374361/), for those eager to help, it can be accessed with their 10 day trial. This problem is from video 17/48.

thank you, if you need additional information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two of your Jinja templates you reference the `@property` `view.current`. However, since the property throws an `HTTPNotFound()` exception, your Jinja templates end up hitting that and explode, causing your problem.

Either remove the calls to `view.current` from your Jinja templates or modify your `view.current` function so that it doesn't throw.

I'm not sure if this is the solution you are looking for, but it doesn't deviate from the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

This is a different `HTTPNotFound` exception and it is raised at the route-matching step before your view is even executed. The reason is that you have `config.add_route('view', '/{id}')`. Note the `/{id}` **NOT** `/{id}/`. Pyramid considers these two different routes and thus the latter does not match. The simplest solution to this is to register all of our canonical routes with a `/` suffix such as `/{id}/` and then pass `append_slash=True` to your notfound view configuration such as `config.add_notfound_view(..., append_slash=True)` or `@notfound_view_config(append_slash=True)`. This will trigger a redirect when a user visits the version without the trailing slash.

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately this does not solve the main problem that I am having. I added more of my error log so you can see where the issue is coming from. I apologize for not doing this sooner. 

The problem, I believe, is the line **raise HTTPNotFound()** is called